# Detect whether a loaded image is a SVG without the file extension

Tags: javascript, html

I need to know where an image file is an SVG (for fallback) but the CMS I'm using doesn't give away the file extension in the URL.

How can I still know if a loaded image is a SVG?

(The URLs look like this `domain.com/files/images/100` with 100 being the id of the image.)

Comment: How is the file getting 'loaded'? You're just referencing a URL, and there's no way to know by simply typing in a URL what resource exists on the server -- you haven't made the request until you attempt to retrieve it.

Comment: Does the server serve the file with the correct content type? If so it must have that stored somewhere in the CMS. SVG is "image/svg+xml".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

URLs don't determine file type anyway, example.com/foo.jpg could be an SVG. What determines file type is the `content-type` HTTP header, which we can obtain efficiently via a HEAD request, which fetches headers but not the image itself.

```
async function urlIsSvg(url) {
  const r = await fetch(url, {method: 'HEAD'});
  return r.headers.get('content-type') === 'image/svg+xml';
}

console.log(
  await urlIsSvg('https://picsum.photos/100'),
  await urlIsSvg('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/30/Vector-based_example.svg'),
);
```

Comment: Would whoever's downvoting please comment why?

Answer (score 2):

You might send a `HEAD` request and get a `content-type` header:

```js
var src = 'https://picsum.photos/100';

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       console.log(this.getResponseHeader('content-type'))
    }
};
xhttp.open("HEAD", src, true);
xhttp.send();
```

Comment: Here's an SVG image you can use: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/30/Vector-based_example.svg